# JavaFX Image cannot find resources in Eclipse

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception, eclipse-oxygen

I've read around numerable posts on how to add images to my JavaFX desktop application. Screenshot below of my project structure and code that is trying to grab the image. Everytime, every contruct I try, I get NULL pointer exceptions thrown trying to create the new Image. I have my resources stored to a source folder under the main project and this is on the classpath of the build. I have no idea why it would keep generating a NULL. Any advice appreciated.

[Click for Project Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlLqQ.png)

```
ImageView thumbView = new ImageView();
        try {
            Image thumb = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("eol.jpg"));
            thumbView.setImage(thumb);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Could not find image %s", e));
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getClass().getResourceAsStream() will look for the resource in the same package as your class, but your image is in the root.

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/eol.jpg");
```

You can also move the image from resources/eol.jpg to resources/eol/eol.jpg/.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)